# Filter for "contains text" with OR or CASE to allow multiple options in NetSuite. Custom field: Keyword Match option seems available

Tags: sql, search, formula, netsuite

NetSuite formula(text) problem.

I have a specific search I need to power up but I could also really use this for general use across a few types of reporting.

We use a lot of custom body fields which do not seem to have access to the Keyword Match option in the dropdown system or I would be using commas left and right.

I need to search a single custom field for multiple possible answers.

I was thinking maybe a CASE WHEN formula but I don't have an else.

Lets call the field states. I want this report to only return rows of records where there are the following 5 states in the custom body field "Shipping State". it isn't allowing keyword match. I only want to see transactions with Michigan, New Jersey and Floria (this is hypothetical) so I want just to put a filter in up front to pair down the results.

CASE WHEN {custbody.shippingstate} IS 'Michigan' ...

Can I use an OR construct here? and do I need an else?

I tried using coalesce but I don't think I had the syntax around the coalese right.

Any help for a formula newbie appreciated.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Something like this? oone sec formatting

Comment: Hey, not as a comment (too hard to read), edit your question instead.

Comment: Sorry @jarlh I got thrown a different work assignment and this project got folded for a while. Sorry the original post was insufficient. I was trying to remove any NDA data from an example when this got reprioritized. Thanks for responding though! Next time I will include benign sample data in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following as a formula text result column in a NetSuite saved search.

```
CASE WHEN LOWER({custbody.shippingstate}) LIKE '%michigan%' 
 OR LOWER({custbody.shippingstate}) LIKE '%jersey%' 
 OR LOWER({custbody.shippingstate}) LIKE '%florida%' 
THEN 'Y' END
```

LIKE conditions are case sensitive, so that's why I incorporated the LOWER() method.  Reminder in NetSuite "%" matches any string of any length (including zero length, and "_" matches a single character.  If this works as a results column you can add the formula text as a criteria to filter results.

Comment: Thank you @martha ! Sorry for the late response! I got tossed a different work query and this project went to the wayside. I tested this and I really helped!

Comment: Ah.. THANK YOU! I finally found out what I did wrong with the syntax with my formula. I used (if I would use your example): custbody.shippingstate = 'michigan'.. which wouldn't return anything at all. Now I know I need to use LIKE. Thanks again!